# Why is GParted telling me I have 239.12 GiB of storage on a 64 Gib flashdrive?

Tags: kubuntu, desktop-environments, reinstall

I installed desktop environments and had issues.

I uninstalled Windows from the dual boot (not smart) and formatted the external hard drive I used for the install. For some reason the computer doesn't identify the drive at all now, but GParted does.

Is there a way to reinstall Kubuntu via the terminal? I'm afraid my HD is fried potatoes.

Answer (score 0):

You can run terminal commands, so I think we can manage this problem. Install ***mkusb-nox*** or the not yet officially released version ***dus***. mkusb-nox tools can install a live system and dus can install a live or a persistent live system with Kubuntu in the external drive (both work in text mode, dus can work in graphics mode too), if that is what you want.

See the following links

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb

[Installation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/gui#Installation)

[dus - a revamped interface of mkusb and mkusb-nox](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/gui#dus_-_a_revamped_interface_of_mkusb_and_mkusb-nox)

Or do you want to make a full installation of Kubuntu into the same drive as where you have the text mode system? It might be possible, but more tricky, because I suspect that that you have to edit the partition table in text mode. It might be better to do it in several steps:

1. Create a live drive (in the USB HDD or in USB pendrive or in a DVD disk),
2. Boot from that live drive and install Kubuntu into the internal drive.

-o-

You can check the S.M.A.R.T. status of the HDD. In graphics mode you can use Disks alias gnome-disks, and in text mode you can install **smartmontools** and use ***smartctl*** for this purpose. (See the manual to find out how to use it. Ask in a comment here, if you need help to select options.)

```
sudo apt-get install smartmontools
man smartctl
```

Answer (score 0):

I will answer the question in the title separately:

There is some confusion because of the sector size. I think Gparted 'is tricked into believing' that the sector size is four times bigger than what it is. And then there is the conversion between MB (megabyte, base 10) and MiB (mibibyte, base 2)

```
$ bc
scale=2
4*64*10^9/2^30
238.41
```

I think the difference to 239.12 GiB is because the size is not exactly 64 MB.